How to dynamically add images with nextjs version 14
I built an admin panel where you add images for projects. The following javascript code is the action that helps me to do it.
export const createProduct = async (state, formData) => {
  const result = productSchema.safeParse(
    Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())
  );

  console.log(result.error);

  if (result.success === false) return result.error.formErrors.fieldErrors;

  const {
    title,
    vendorCode,
    image,
    categoryId,
    characteristics,
    mainCategoryId,
    price,
  } = result.data;

  const data = result.data;
  await fs.mkdir("public/products", { recursive: true });
  const imagePath = `/products/${crypto.randomUUID()}-${data.image.name}`;
  await fs.writeFile(
    `public${imagePath}`,
    Buffer.from(await data.image.arrayBuffer())
  );

  const product = await db.product.create({
    data: {
      title,
      slug: slugify(`${title}-${vendorCode}`, {
        locale: "ru",
        lower: true,
      }),
      image: imagePath,
      categoryId,
      vendorCode,
      mainCategoryId,
      price,
    },
  });

  await db.productCharacteristic.createMany({
    data: characteristics.map((char) => ({
      title: char.title,
      variants: char.values.map(({ value }) => value),
      productId: product.id,
    })),
  });
  revalidatePath("/");
  redirect("/admin/catalog");

Here is how I use the product image.
<Image
  className="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover"
  src={product.image}
  width={800}
  height={800}
  alt={product.title}
/>

In development mode, it works fine, but it errors when trying to cloud host it in production mode. The images are supposed to be taken from the /_next/image folder. However, when adding a new product, the image doesn't move to the correct directory (/_next/image) until you do an npm run build.
My question is, how can I make the image go into the /_next/image directory and be displayed on the site without having to run npm run build?
I tried to use minimumCacheTTL but it didn't work
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  env: {
    SERVER_URL: process.env.SERVER_URL,
  },
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 60,
  },
};

export default nextConfig;


According to documentation:


Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at request time won't be available. We recommend using a third-party service like Vercel Blob
for persistent file storage.


In other words, Next.js is not supposed to provide storage and serving of dynamic assets. You should use other services for keeping them.

This is useful for my project with nginx.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

    # Root directory
    root /path/to/your/nextjs/project;

    # Handle requests for static files directly
    location /_next/static/ {
        alias /path/to/your/nextjs/project/.next/static/;
        expires 365d;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Handle uploaded files
    location /uploads/ {
        alias /path/to/your/nextjs/project/public/uploads/;
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }

    # All other requests go to the Next.js server
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Assuming Next.js runs on port 3000
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

And I think we can use custom server with nextjs
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14121#discussioncomment-7731025
